# Download PDF without saving in ASP.net Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, save, handler

I've a handler in asp.net app. When there comes some kind of request I want user to get download window, where I put **PDF** stream. I don't want PDF to be saved in memory.
I have the following code, but it fails to open, says pdf file was demaged and couldn't open it.
tell me other way to achieve my goal if you think mine is not good.

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                CreatePFD(T.Text, stream);

                context.Response.Write(stream);


                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Nots__Saved__FIle__fileName.pdf");
```

Now I have this code:

Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
                System.IO.Stream outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\c\wefwe.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

```
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, outputStream);

            Doc.Open();

            List<IElement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(T.Text), null);
            for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
            {
                Doc.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
            }

            outputStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            Doc.Close();

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Nots__Saved__FIle__fileName.pdf");
```

when i save pdf, the file is correct...
but when I get response the file is in correct. demaged...

Comment: That should be a `MemoryStream`

Comment: It is. I made a misstake

Answer (score 3):

You need to rewind the stream by setting `stream.Position = 0`.

Also, `Response.Write(stream)` will just print `stream.ToString()`.

Instead, you should call `stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream)`.

Comment: Which only works in .NET 4 and higher. There are many other stream copy functions around though, if you need them.

Comment: I think the copy didn't worked for me besides I use 4.0 net
there are some errors like this:
Length = 'context.Response.OutputStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: @levanlevi: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks that was my mistake, I closed. now that's not problem, but I can't get correct pdf file even now.

Comment: You need to close and rewind the stream before copying it.

Comment: When I close this error is risen:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

Comment: @levanlevi: Try flushing instead, or try telling the PDF library not to close the stream